# How to make a deep copy of a Hosted Feature Service

Tags: python, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-python-api

How can I make a deep copy of a Hosted Feature Service using ArcGIS Python for API?

My hosted feature service has one layer. I'd like to copy the hosted feature service **and** the layer. (I want to generate identical hosted feature services from a template in order to run some tests.)

Following code using [`arcgis.gis.Item.copy`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.Item.copy) creates a copied feature service (but not a hosted feature service) referencing the original layer.

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS

gis = GIS(username="username", password="password")
item = gis.content.get("cabd3aa111111111111111111111111")
copied_item = item.copy()  # makes a shallow copy
```

I came across with [`arcgis.gis.GIS.content.clone_items`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/cloning-content/) but my understanding is that it intended to use to copy content across organizations. I need a copy on the same server environment.

[`arcgis.gis.Item.copy_feature_layer_collection`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.Item.copy_feature_layer_collection) allows to specify which layers should be considered and it creates a hosted feature class with the specified layers but data is not copied.